# Apache Beam/Java, how to set window/trigger that sends the data only once for each window

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a pipeline as below:

```
Window<String> fixedWindow = Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowDuration())))
      .triggering(
        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
          .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime
            .pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowDuration()))))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
      .discardingFiredPanes();

PCollectionTuple productProcessorPT = pipeline
  .apply(READ_PRODUCT_FROM_PUBSUB.getName(), PubsubIO.readStrings()
    .fromSubscription(options.getProductSubscription()))
  .apply(PRODUCT_WINDOW.getName(), fixedWindow)
  .apply(PROCESS_PRODUCT.getName(), ParDo.of(new ProductProcessor()))
  .apply(GROUP_PRODUCT_DATA.getName(), GroupByKey.create())
  .apply(COMBINE_PRODUCT_DATA.getName(), ParDo.of(new ProductCombiner())
    .withOutputTags(KV_STRING_OBJECTNODE, TupleTagList.of(PIPELINE_ERROR)));
```

What I want to achieve is to set a window/trigger that gather the data every 60s, and then send the data to next transform. How can I do that? I don't care the event timestamp.

The code above send data to next transform every 60s, but it also keeps triggering/sending (the same) data even there is no new data come in to the pipeline. No sure why that happens?

Comment: HI @MichaelXiao, welcome to StackOverflow and your first great question.
Since the title of a question helps to attract the right answers, maybe replace "my case" with something more descriptive like "that sends the same data only once"

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the triggering and just use `FixedWindows` as below to emit records every 60 seconds

```
Window<String> fixedWindow = Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowDuration())));
```

This will use default triggering and handling of late events which would basically mean that the data is emitted at the end of the window and all late events are ignored.

Comment: using the default trigger is the first thing I have tried, but weird thing is if I just use the default trigger, there will be no data output for transform 'ProductCombiner' at all. and I'm thinking use the window/trigger as below:  `Window<String> fixedWindow = Window.<String>into(new GlobalWindows())
      .triggering(
        Repeatedly.forever(
          AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(options.getWindowDuration()))))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
      .discardingFiredPanes();` does this will have any side effects?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by no data output for tranform `ProductCombiner` ? Are you suggesting that with default trigger post the GroupBy no records are getting emitted?

Comment: Yes, if I use default `trigger`, post the GroupBy there is no records are getting emitted, which means there is no records being outputted from the whole pipleline. If I use the window/trigger in my post, I could get the output post the GroupBy, but the issue is the elements count in PCollection.out for `ProductCombiner` never drop, and from the log I see `ProductCombiner` process the first element successfully, then trying to process the same data again and again and get exception, this make me think the trigger in my post some how keep triggering in some condition.